# How to disable ESLint in react native project?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, eslint

I am new to React native Project. I am working on React native latest version 0.61.5 now. The whole project is showing red underline. The reason is ESLint and I want to disable I don't know how to proceed. can anyone please suggest me the way of handling that ESLint in Project.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should fix the issues rather than adding a `eslint-disable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi you can use this to ignore ESLint for some files or path you want
==> https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-disable

[image]

Comment: the above one I tried, it is working, but only one line which is import * as React from 'react';  showing error like  "Parsing error: The keyword 'import' is reserved(undefined)"

Comment: Or simply just by deleting the .eslint file from your project disables eslint. For me its the easiest fix i love

Answer (score 7):

You could place `/* eslint-disable */` at the top of your file to tell ESLint to ignore it.

[More disabling rules docs](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments)

If you wish to disable eslint for the whole project, you should disabled it in your config

Answer (score 2):

If you are using VS Code, you should go to extensions and whether eslint is installe.If installed just disable it and refresh the project